# Difference in HttpContext between NTLM and Kerberos

Tags: c#, kerberos, ntlm, httpcontext

We have a web site that currently uses windows authentication with NTLM.

In this solution we have some code that reads the user name out of the HttpContext.

We are now considering moving to Kerberos.

Question is: will this affect the user name in the HttpContext?

**Edit**

We are using:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are are you referring to HttpContext.User - I believe that it shouldn't matter whether windows authentication is done using kerberos or NTLM. HttpContext.User should continue to return windows principal.